# Sorted order in Flux of custom class

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

Suppose I have a class Student with attributes name and height.

```
class Student{ String name; double height;}
```

If I have a flux of objects of students and I want to the output to be sorted in ascending order of the student's name, then how do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you have an array of student objects as follows:

```
Student[] students = {studentObj1, studentObj2, studentObj3};
```

You just need to use a Comparator, which in Java 8/ reactive programming can be written as a lambda function, in the [sort](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#sort--) method provided by Flux.

Here obj1 and obj2 are the objects of Student class which are compared to each other.

obj1.compareTo(obj2) sorts them in ascending order.

```
Flux.fromIterable (Arrays.asList(students)).sort( (obj1, obj2) -> obj1.getName().compareTo(obj2.getName()));
```

Comment: Its not clear from the answer what attribute of Student object is compared with? What if I want to compare student lastName?

Answer (score 6):

Accepter [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50664695/472784) works but instead of rolling your own comperator you can also use method references, given that the class has getters:

```java
class Student { 
   String name; 
   double height;

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   // more getters
}
```

You can then do:

```
Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(students)).sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName))
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50664695/472784) is OK but I'd suggest a different way.

If what you have is an array of Students, then you can just sort using [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) and then create a Flux from the sorted array calling [Flux.fromArray](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#fromArray-T:A-).

But if you have a Flux of student, not array, Flux have a operator to do that job specifically - [Flux.collectSortedList](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectSortedList--)

```
Flux studentFlux = Flux.just(studentOne,studentTwo);
studentFlux.collectSortedList((studentObj1, studentObj2) -> studentObj1.getName().compareTo(studentObj2.getName()))
```